# Add two "document.getElementById" to calculate how much to offsetTop

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp for implementing a sticky navigation bar for my website, but unlike the example on that page, my site has two "navbar" divs - one on top of the other.  I want to have the bottom bar become sticky once it reaches the top of the page, but when I implement according to the tutorial, it doesn't become sticky until For the purpose of this question, label one "logobar" and the other "navbar".

How can I add the heights of both bars to calculate the offsetTop to use in the w3schools' `var sticky = *calculatedvalue*.offsetTop;` statement?

In addition to this, in the tutorial, there's a `.sticky + .content` padding-top set at 60px, which is static.  In my case, both of my "logobar" and "navbar" are wrapped in a div wrapped by the , and the following "content" is the blog "main"  at the same level as the .  So how would I add a padding that is a calculate of the entire  so that my sticky navbar doesn't go off-screen and then rubber-band to its sticky position?  So that it's dynamic if the total header height changes on a device of different screen width.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: top: 0; ...... plus the height of your nav bar... eg if your nav bar is 40px then top:0 would be top: 40px;  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky

Comment: do you want the next one to replace the first one and same going forward... so each one replaces the last... and then reverse when you scroll the other way again.